# Make panoramic images from few images taken from one position

Tags: c#, image-processing

Does anybody know some open-source framework, code examples etc for the follwoing problem? I have a few images of the same object. Need to find a way how to stitch them into one panoramic image.

Answer (score 3):

See [Panorama Tools](http://panotools.sourceforge.net/).

The project is also active (not zombie open source projects).

Another way is to get a command line based tool and use calls the program directly in your program.

If you are interested in creating implementations on your own, most existing algorithms are usually published as academic papers. A good way to find better algorithms is to rank them by citation rate. You can find them using [Google Scholar here](http://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=panoramic+algorithm&hl=en&btnG=Search).

Answer (score 1):

Try [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/).  This is an open source GUI for Panorama Tools.  Panorama tools does have a basic GUI, but Hugin is superior.